# Amazon AWS how to configure servers to scale?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm fairly new to amazon, not to Linux, routing, web serving/hosting. So please be patient with me and my novice AWS questions.

The company I work for has a team building an application that they don't want hosted internally and are pushing to AWS. I have played with and configured a couple hosting servers in AWS but not to this complexity. I understand VPC and EC2 and have working knowledge of S3.

I have searched through the web, but no where does it detail how the scaling part works, and I'm not talking about automated scaling. I'm interested to know how the actual server configuration works.

For instance, we have a jar file and properties files that need to be deployed to a server in order to have a running site. The questions is, where do I place these files, so that if I wanted to scale to another bigger or smaller resource instance, it would use those same files? My research seems to be pointing to "EBS" and S3 for this setup, but I'm not to clear on how... I guess the question is, how do I configure instances to read site files?

My question is presuming that at any given point I have one instance running and reading the site files, and if I wanted to use a bigger instance or a smaller instance I would shutdown the current instance and boot up a new instance, of course, while always reading from the same site files..

My scenario may not be the correct way to create a scalable architecture, so if you have a better suggestion, than I'm all ears. This is how I've understood the scalable aspect of AWS works. And keeping in mind I'm using the scaling up or down approach and not the scaling out, which scaling out suggests having more than one instance running in order to balance computation between instances and increasing the cost by instances running..

Clarity would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you choose EBS drives for your server then you can stop the server, change the size, and restart it without losing any data on the drive. This will allow you to add more CPU/RAM to your single server.

If you want a more scalable architecture you should design your system to work well on multiple servers behind a load balancer. Then you can use Autoscaling Groups or Elastic Beanstalk to automatically add and remove servers to the pool based on current system load.

Comment: I'm trying to use Centos 7 for building multiple different scalable servers from aws market. 

First issue, and I don't know if this is an issue but the aws image won't let me make quick launch of multiple different instances of the centos 7 image... Two) If I use the load balancer, doesn't that mean that I would need to have multiple instances running for the balance to have options to balance between?

Three) When you say add or remove servers, does this mean shutdown and boot up? I ask, because to my understanding, it's not billable if I have instances created and not running.

Comment: Your Quick Launch issue sounds like something you could create another question for on this site. A load balancer doesn't force you to have multiple, you can scale down to a single instance with a load balancer, but obviously the point is to be able to scale up to multiple servers to have the load distributed across them. When I say add/remove servers I mean creating and deleting new server instances from an AMI, although you could have multiple servers that you shut down and startup. You are still charged for storage usage on shutdown instances though.

Comment: I figured out the the first issue, which wasn't an issue, it was my lack of knowing. Now, I created a load balancer and it's not working as I thought it would. I deleted the 4 instaces and I'll explain the scenario I thought I was building for. I created 4 instances, one greater than the previous in resources, and I removed all volumes that were created with each one. I also created ONE actual volume that will be where I store the site data and this volume would get attached and detached when I needed to scale between severs "up or down".

Comment: I created the load balancer which I'm trying to rap my head around how it works. It asked to me add a server to it, so I thought, ok it's going to create all the instances I need and all I need to do is point it to the right volume and the balancer will do the rest... But your statement now makes me interpret that the load balancer asked me for an instance to scale up to from the instance I physically created on my own. Of which I'm not sure how the load balancer would know how to attach the volume I created just for the site files. Of which is why I deleted all the instances I created initily

Comment: EBS volumes can't be used by more than one server at a time. You could use Elastic File System for that purpose but it is in beta right now. Load Balancers don't create instances or scale up/down themselves. You would define an Autoscaling Group, or use Elastic Beanstalk for the scaling part. Load Balancers simply distribute your incoming traffic among the instances that have been added to it. You need to look up how AMI (Amazon Machine Images) work. I think you are trying to use EBS volumes when you should be using an AMI.

Comment: Honestly, for people that aren't experienced in this stuff, I would highly recommend you use Elastic Beanstalk which handles all of this for you, instead of trying to configure all the pieces yourself.

Comment: So I think your right, I might be looking at this the wrong way. In simple terms, let me ask you. How would you host a site in AWS where you could scale the resources needed and having the site files in the same place... To my understanding the instance needs to change for the resources to change, and if that happens, how do I manage the site files to be on those changing instances..? I hope this question makes sense..

Comment: With Elastic Beanstalk all the site configuration and application code will be pulled from your Git repository whenever a server is created, and any updates to your Git repository will be pushed to any existing servers to keep them up to date. If you have static files such as images that need to be shared across multiple servers and they aren't stored in Git, then you can use S3 for that (or some other distributed file system service such as DropBox for Apps).

Comment: I don't think beanstalk is the way for us... Lets take this to simple terms, see if maybe you can propose a process. If you had a simple html site hosted in an instance running on a aws market place centos box and you wanted to to scale up and down to bigger and smaller instances, how would you do it?

Comment: If you have a *SINGLE* instance that you want to scale up/down, then I already answered that in my original answer. You shutdown the server, change the instance size to a larger or smaller size, and then start the server back up. You might have to tweak your application server's configuration settings to allow it to use more or less RAM based on the new server size. Are you just hosting a static HTML site or are you hosting some sort of PHP site or something with some dynamic page views? If you just have a static HTML site there are much cheaper and easier ways to host it.

Comment: Ok, that's what I'm planning to do. The thing is, I wanted to automate the scale depending on traffic or load to scale up in peak and scale down off peak. I understand the need to shutdown and boot back up while detaching and reattaching the EBS volume to each instance. I want to push that all into an automation. What we have is jar file, properies files and front end UI files. Which I was thinking server 1) attached are two EBS, one for the jars/properties files and the other volume for the UI/Front end files.

Comment: And if there was a lack of resources, I would shutdown the server detach the volumes and attach them the the new server with more resources and boot it up. I'm trying to figure out a way where I don't have downtime, meaning boot up with a copy or newly attached EBS volumes so that there is barely a downtime....

Comment: No, there is no reason to create a new server and move the volume around to get "more resources". As I've said, you simply change the server instance type while it is shutdown, and that adds more resources to the existing server.

Comment: So I'll figure out how to change the instace type to something greater, now that I know that's possible. So the next question, since you've cleared a lot up for me, is, is there a way to change the instance without stopping services.. ex. have two, one running and one not running so that if I had to upgrade resources one one, I could boot the other one up with the same EBS volumes..? I want to be able to keep site live somehow while I update a server..

Comment: EBS volumes can't be shared. If you could describe your application better I could offer more specific advise. Is it just static HTML files, or is it some sort of dynamic application? Do the files on the server change often? Do users upload files to the server or otherwise cause files to be changed on the server?

Comment: It is a java based site. Our front end is coded with Jetty,NGINX, and backend is using mysql and also Jetty. There isn't static files being uploaded, it's mostly querying information from backend after inputting information from the front end... "Static" files are in the war file, and executed with java 7

Comment: The only files that consist of our web server is backend = jar file and properties file and front end = war file.

Comment: Elastic Beanstalk Tomcat servers and a MySQL or Aurora RDS database would be perfect for your system. If you don't want to use EB, then you could build a system image that automatically checks out your latest code on startup before it starts your Java server. Then you could easily add/remove servers to a load balanced pool. You could also look into OpenShift or Heroku which are both PaaS offerings similar to Elastic Beanstalk that also run on Amazon Web Services.

Answer (score 0):

[AWS OpsWorks](https://aws.amazon.com/opsworks/) will allow you to use Chef recipes (written with Ruby) to deploy code and resources to your servers as your needs change.

- Create a "Stack"
- Configure Applications within your "Stack"
- Put Instances in your Application (EC2s)
- Deploy

An alternative, would be to use [ECS (Elastic Container Service)](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/) with Docker to put your jar files into appropriately sized containers.

- Create a Cluster
- Add Task Definitions
- Configure Auto Scaling Group (instance type, desired size, etc)
- Launch

Both of these options can be configured with an Auto Scaling Group (in EC2) to quickly adjust the amount of resources based on need and deploy your code in a consistent and automated way.

That's the gist of it, anything beyond this would be a full blown tutorial which will be based heavily on your architecture. I'd recommend reading some guides, hitting up the documentation and giving it a try.

For Bonus Points, check out [CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/), which will allow you to configure your AWS resources/provisions in code, so you don't need to fiddle with the UI to make adjustments or to (re)deploy.

Comment: I think a more detail approach is what I'm looking for, though this is good information. I'm trying to start with EC2 to not over complicate what I don't know yet with the other AWS tools.

If you could give me more details on configuration, that would be great, using EC2...

Thanks,